# Множественный рендеринг моделей Libgdx

Tags: java, android, opengl, libgdx

кто может подсказать, хочу отрисовать одну модель, в разных местах на карте, прочитал, что можно сделать один меш, и через вершинный шейдер рендерить меш в разных местах, чтобы не падала производительность ?
Так как, если рендерить через ModelInstace сразу проседает fps, кто знает, как рендерить множество одинаковых моделей без просадки?

Comment: а разве это сильный прирост дает? ну не считая оперативы, но ее вроде ща у всех дофига.